# Excel VBA Collect Data from other Excel Files and paste them into Masterfile

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a C# Programmer and new into Excel VBA and here I am on my limit.
I don't get the gist how to copy and paste data from different files into one Masterfile..

I want to collect all data from Excel Files in a userdefined folder. These data were always stored in excel files. 
And always starts at the D column until last column from the 6th row to last row.

So I want first to get the Parent directory in which I get all the Files in this Parentfolder.
After that I start the `CollectSubdata`Procedure.

So my approach would be copy the range from each subfile and paste them into the 6th row and last column of my masterfile

```
Private Sub CollectData()

Dim MasterWorkbook As Workbook
Set MasterWorkbook = Workbooks("Masterfile.xlsm")

Dim Folderpath As String
'Get Folder which contains all Data
Folderpath = UserGetFolder & "\"

Dim obj As Object
Dim ParentFolder As Object
Dim Files As Object

Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ParentFolder = obj.GetFolder(Folderpath)
Set Files = ParentFolder.Files

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop through all folder now
Dim subfile As Object
For Each subfile In ParentFolder.Files

'Start Data Collection
Call CollectSubdata(subfile)

Next subfile


End Sub
```

Here my Sub Procedure

```
Private Sub CollectSubdata(ByRef subfile As Object)

' Do Data collection here
Dim subwb As Workbook
Dim LastColumn As Double
Dim LastRow As Double
Dim LastMasterCol As Double

LastMasterCol = MasterWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set subwb = Workbooks.Open(subfile)
LastColumn = subwb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = subwb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Copy all necessary entries
subwb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(6, 4), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy

'Paste into Masterfile
MasterWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(6, LastMasterCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

subwb.Close
End Sub
```

And Here my Userdefined Folder

```
Function UserGetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    UserGetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

I don't get the gist of VBA uses these objects and methods..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collecting data from files in folders with VBA and excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109416/collecting-data-from-files-in-folders-with-vba-and-excel)

Comment: Don't refer me to any stuff I've read already, I want to know why I cant access the Masterworkbook in the Subfile in the paste method

Comment: I have no idea what you have (or have not) read already, because you say nothing about any of that in your question. Check the attitude and mind your manners - see the [help] for some information about acceptable conduct here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable only exists in the context in which it is defined. In your case the pointer masterworkbook is defined within the routine CollectData so it only exists within that routine. In order to get it into CollectSubData you either need to pass a reference to it as an argument to the subroutine, or define the variable at module level so that it exists for all routines within that module. The former is better practice, so you should define your CollectSubData as

```
 Private Sub CollectSubdata(ByRef subfile As Object, ByRef MasterWorkbook As Workbook)
```

and call it as

```
 'Start Data Collection
 CollectSubdata(subfile,MasterWorkbook)
```

Note that Call is not needed in this context (although it's not wrong per se)